# Making a simple countdown timer with Clojure/Reagent

Tags: clojure, reagent

I am experimenting with Clojure and Reagent with almost no experience, trying to make a simple timer.

```
(defn reset-component [t]
  [:input {:type "button" :value "Reset"
           :on-click #(reset! t 60)}])

(defn countdown-component []
  (let [seconds-left (atom 60)]
    (fn []
      (js/setTimeout #(swap! seconds-left dec) 1000)
      [:div.timer
        [:div "Time Remaining: " (show-time @seconds-left)]
        [reset-component seconds-left]])))
```

The timer countdown appears to work correctly until I hit the reset button. After that, the timer starts counting down twice as fast. Every time I hit the reset button it counts down faster.

How can I get the timer to automatically count down when the page is loaded but not count down faster when the reset button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found was to use `setInterval` before the component function rather than `setTimeout` inside the component function:

```
(defn reset-component [seconds]
  [:input {:type "button" :value "Reset"
           :on-click #(reset! seconds 60)}])

(defn countdown-component []
  (let [seconds-left (atom 60)]
    (js/setInterval #(swap! seconds-left dec) 1000)
    (fn []
      [:div.timer
       [:div "Time Remaining: " @seconds-left]
       [reset-component seconds-left]])))
```

Comment: For people who are not aware, the `atom` mentioned here is `reagent.core/atom`.

Answer (score 5):

Dereferencing seconds-left in reset-component triggers a rerender of the countdown component which attaches another decrementer function to your countdown-component.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, `reagent` 0.6.0+ comes with a new `with-let` macro, very useful for things that need proper "destruction", such as the `setInterval`/`clearInterval`:

```
(defn countdown-component []
  (r/with-let [seconds-left (r/atom 60)
               timer-fn     (js/setInterval #(swap! seconds-left dec) 1000)]
        [:div.timer
          [:div "Time Remaining: " (str @seconds-left)]]
    (finally (js/clearInterval timer-fn))))
```

Here's the official [anouncement](https://reagent-project.github.io/news/news060-alpha.html) of the feature.

Note that calling `setTimeout` from the render function also works, but it is not seen as good practice. (e.g. https://clojurians.slack.com/archives/C0620C0C8/p1495568238109060)

Comment: I don't see how the timer knows to stop ticking once it reaches zero...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
(defn reset-component [t]
  [:input {:type "button" :value "Reset"
           :on-click #(reset! t 60)}])

(defn countdown-component []
  (let [seconds-left (atom 60)]
    (js/setInterval #(swap! seconds-left dec) 1000)
    (fn []  
      [:div.timer
        [:div "Time Remaining: " (show-time @seconds-left)]
        [reset-component seconds-left]])))
```

Notice that now call to `setInterval` happens only at component initialization and not during the render phase.

Comment: Note that this only works if you change `setTimeout` to `setInterval`